# Is there way to make SQL+ accept a parameter that isn't a number?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm stuck on this Homework problem for Oracle Plus, so any pointers in the right direction would be great. I need to...

"1.Create a script that will take an parameter of division(DIV) with script execution and generate employee report for all employee in this division."

Here's the layout of the relevant tables

**Divisions**
-Division_ID, Name

**Employees2**, Employee_ID, Division_ID, Job_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Salary

So far I have

```
SET DEFINE '#'
SELECT Last_Name || ‘,’ || first_name AS Name, Divisions.Name

FROM Employees INNER JOIN Divisions 
ON Employees2.Division_ID = Divisions.Divisions_ID

WHERE Division_ID = #v_Division_ID
```

It asks me for the division_id input but when i put it in it doesn't work. Now being that the Division_ID column isn't a number but rather an abbreviation like "SAL" for sales It seems that the error is because oracle plus wont take letters as input but rather only numbers? Is there a way to make this script so it accepts string/data that isn't numbers but rather something like "sal"?

Comment: What is "Oracle Plus"?

Comment: Try `...WHERE Division_ID = '#v_Division_ID'`

Comment: I assume you mean SQL*Plus and not Oracle+, right?

Answer (score 0):

When the substitution variable is being compared to a VARCHAR2, you want to enter the value you want to supply, e.g. 'SAL', with single quotation marks around it.

Here is an example from the SCOTT sample schema:

```
SCOTT@dev> SET DEFINE '#'
SCOTT@dev> 
SCOTT@dev> 
SCOTT@dev> SELECT e.ename employee_name
  2  FROM emp e
  3  INNER JOIN dept d
  4  ON e.deptno   = d.deptno
  5  WHERE d.dname = #v_dname
  6  /
Enter value for v_dname: 'SALES'
old   5: WHERE d.dname = #v_dname
new   5: WHERE d.dname = 'SALES'

EMPLOYEE_N
==========
ALLEN
WARD
MARTIN
BLAKE
TURNER
JAMES

6 rows selected.
```

Thus for you, you just need to enter 'SAL' for your #v_Division_ID.